# Mysterious Segmentation Fault in C++ Code

Tags: c++, memory

It's been a while since I've coded C++ and I'm having some issues with this code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string* data;
int current = 0;

void init(){
    data = new string[6];
    data[0] = "7 4 3";
    data[1] = "8 11 12 16 17 18 20";
    data[2] = "17 16 20 2 20 5 13";
    data[3] = "17 8 8 16 12 15 13";
    data[4] = "12 4 16 4 15 7 6";
    data[5] = "8 14 2 11 17 12 8";
}

string getNext() {
    if(current == 0){
        init();
    }
    return data[current++];
}

void populate(int* target, int n){
    target = new int[n];
    string line = getNext();
    stringstream ss(line);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        ss >> target[i];
        cout << target[i] << endl;
    }
    // THIS WORKS FINE
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << "TARGET" << target[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    string line;
    int n, s, e;
    int* x, * a, * b, * c, *d;

    line = getNext();
    stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> n >> s >> e;
    cout << "N: " << n << " S: " << s << " E: " << e << endl;

    populate(x, n);

    // IMMEDIATE SEGMENTATION FAULT ON FIRST ITERATION
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    populate(a, n);
    populate(b, n);
    populate(c, n);
    populate(d, n);

    return 0;
}
```

In this program's final form, it will take user input, but for now I'm simulating input with an array of strings that I can read like I would read from cin.

I have several pointers for integer arrays that I'm going to dynamically allocate and fill in each with one line of string input.

I wrote the function `populate()` to do this for me so that I don't have too much duplicated code.

`populate()` seems to load the data fine into the specified pointer. I can even print it back out before returning from the function.

HOWEVER, if I try to read the pointer AFTER `populate()` returns, I get an immediate segmentation fault. Any idea why? Is the reference being lost once the function returns? Do I have to convert the string chunks to ints explicitly in some manner? I'm a bit baffled by this.

**GOT IT: been a while. Thank you!**

Comment: Why are you using all those arrays and pointers instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: You never assigned anything to `x`, so it's an uninitialized pointer and `x[i]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: `populate()` receives `target` by value, so assigning to `target` doesn't modify `x`.

Comment: If you need to change something in the call site from a function you need to pass that something by pointer or reference.  You are not doing either.

Comment: Gotcha! Rusty on c++ like I said. Thanks!

Comment: "I have several pointers for integer arrays that I'm going to dynamically allocate": don't, unless you're practicing or it's a course requirement. You're on the right path with `#include <vector>`. Don't stray from the path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

```
void populate(int* target, int n){
    target = new int[n];
    ...
```

Here you're passing `target` as `int*`, then immediately *reassigning* it locally to the memory allocated, and the coupling to the pointer you passed in is lost. `x` is thus still unitialized inside `main` and accessing it is undefined behavior. Change the type of `target` to `int*&` and it should work for you. You may also use `int**` and pass the address of x, but this will required lots of changes to accessing `target` inside your function.

Comment: If he changes to `int**` he needs to make a bunch of other corresponding changes, like `*target = new int[n];`.

Comment: And also `*target[i]` in the `for` loops.

Comment: i would make this function return the allocated array

Comment: Maybe less confusing to just recommend calling by reference

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. Rusty on C++ forgot that passing pointer in doesn't mean it's same pointer automatically.

Comment: There is no "redefinition" here!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant reassign, thanks for the tip